# Разные версии ноды под рутом и юзером?

Tags: node.js

Под root показывает node -v версию 6... под юзером node -v показываерт версию 0.4... Из-за чего это и как это устанить?

Comment: Какие-нибудь менеджеры версий NodeJS устанавливали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас небось две версии ноды, одна `/usr/bin/node`, другая `/usr/local/bin/node`.

Обычный юзер использует `/usr/local/bin/node`, под рутом `/usr/bin/node`.

По-хорошему, надо удалить `/usr/local/bin/node`.